# iOS 6 the facebook server could not fulfill this access request invalid application

Tags: facebook, sdk, ios6

In some iPhone 5 devices we have an error when trying to call Facebook login:

The error is:
"the facebook server could not fulfill this access request invalid application id"

I many times checked that application id is specified correctly.

Strange, that on other devices same app is working correctly.

Please, could you help, what the reason of that?

Comment: You will find similar question here.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor

Answer (score 17):

All developers of a particular app, should be known to Facebook. While the application is in Sandbox mode (i.e. developer only access), all every user who want to use the Facebook platform, for testing/developing the application, will have to be added as a developer (as shown below) -

Just goto https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, and add the user, in the list of developers/admins.

Comment: 1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com 2. Your app 3. Roles 4. Add Facebook ID of the developer / administrator. 5. To know your Facebook ID: findmyfacebookid.com

Answer (score 5):

More than likely the app is "sandboxed", so only developers have access.  If this is the case you'll have to use a developer account on the iPhone.

1. Go to iOS settings > Facebook
2. Log out with your "personal" account
3. Log in with the developer account (to be safe us the dev account that you created the app with)

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem.  For me the issue was that I hadn't added the iOS platform for the app.  Go to the Facebook developer page, then select your app.  In the left nav bar go to settings.  Then add platform.  Ensure that your bundle identifier is correct.  Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been testing with a sandbox facebook app and then receive this error when switching to the production app **make sure you have published the app** in the status & review tab.