# The facebook server could not fulfil this request: invalid application id

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm using the FBLoginView to login with Facebook in our app.
One of my beta testers is getting the following message and I did not find a way to help him log in

The app is not in sandbox on facebook

[image: Error]

Comment: Try to read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620317/ios-6-the-facebook-server-could-not-fulfill-this-access-request-invalid-applicat 

and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor